# How to divide two rows of same column in SSRS/Powerbi?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, powerbi

```
Account Name          Balance
YTD                   10000
Interest              100
Depreciation          500
Less Distributions    -7000
Plus Paid in Capital  600
Principal             2600
```

I have a table like this I need a new row which gives me the result of division of balance in ytd to interest.

Expected out put:

```
Account Name          Balance
YTD                   10000
Interest              100
Depreciation          500
Less Distributions    -7000
Plus Paid in Capital  600
Principal             2600
Result                100      //(i.e 10000/100)
```

Comment: I think it might be better to pivot the table and do it as a calculated column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!AccountName.Value = "YTD", Fields!Balance.Value, Nothing)) / SUM(IIF(Fields!AccountName.Value = "Interest", Fields!Balance.Value, Nothing))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion i tried it out in SSRS and it worked.